# copy a text in a path (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to copy this information on this route
/usr/share/applications/program.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PhpStorm
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm-182.4129.45/bin/phpstorm.sh
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-182.4129.45/bin/phpstorm.png
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;IDE;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

I will have to adapt it on an existing script, as would be the most ideal way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make these as environment variables? It's not clear from your question what you want to do.

Comment: It is not necessary, I simply have to copy this information. Thank you

Comment: Is the given information contained in a file, and you want to copy the file to desired path? Please suggest more info..

Comment: I just want those lines to show up in the file, I do not mean to copy a file to another route, just text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cat:

```
cat > /usr/share/applications/program.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PhpStorm
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm-182.4129.45/bin/phpstorm.sh
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-182.4129.45/bin/phpstorm.png
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;IDE;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;

EOF
```